# Why am i getting the error and ask me to reshape?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am new to ML. Don't get me wrong. I was trying to predict the year 2020 in Canada for per capita income using the linear regression. but I get error which say for reshaping. why is that and what is the solution?

here's the code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn import linear_model 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


df=pd.read_csv('E:/CV (ALL FOR JOB)/ALL PROJECTS/5. IMAGE DETECTION/canada.csv')
df
df.head(3)

%matplotlib inline 
plt.xlabel('year',fontsize=20)
plt.ylabel('per capita income (US$)',fontsize=20)
plt.scatter(df.year, df['per capita income (US$)'], color='blue', marker='+')
reg = linear_model.LinearRegression()
reg.fit(df.year,df[['per capita income (US$)']])
reg.predict([[2020]])
```

and it says

```
Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[1970 1971 1972 1973 1974 1975 1976 1977 1978 1979 1980 1981 1982 1983
 1984 1985 1986 1987 1988 1989 1990 1991 1992 1993 1994 1995 1996 1997
 1998 1999 2000 2001 2002 2003 2004 2005 2006 2007 2008 2009 2010 2011
 2012 2013 2014 2015 2016].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

Comment: So did  you read the `reg.fit` docs?  Understand what it wants in the arguments.  `df` is a dataframe, `df.year` one column, is a Series, and effectively a 1d array.  `df[['...']]`, with the extra [], is a dataframe, with one column, but effectively a 2d array (n,1) shape.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn import linear_model 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


df=pd.read_csv('E:/CV (ALL FOR JOB)/ALL PROJECTS/5. IMAGE DETECTION/canada.csv')
df
df.head(3)

%matplotlib inline 
plt.xlabel('year',fontsize=20)
plt.ylabel('per capita income (US$)',fontsize=20)

plt.scatter(df.year, df['per capita income (US$)'], color='blue', marker='+')
reg = linear_model.LinearRegression()
new_df = df.drop('per capita income (US$)',axis='columns')
new_df
per=df['per capita income (US$)']
per
reg = linear_model.LinearRegression()
reg.fit(new_df,df['per capita income (US$)'])
reg.predict([[2020]])
```